# Remove string before period in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Is there a way to remove everything before and including the last instance of a dot(.) in a string?

I have these following strings:

1. `packageName.appName.moduleName.eventName.pageNameX`
2. `packageName.appName.moduleName.pageNameY`
3. `packageName.appName.pageNameZ`
4. `packageName.pageNameA`

And I want to have:

1. `pageNameX`
2. `pageNameY`
3. `pageNameZ`
4. `pageNameA`

I have tried:

```
preg_replace('/^.*.\s*/', '', $theString);
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think that second dot should be escaped, i.e. `\.`, otherwise it'll be taken to be "any character".

Comment: `preg_replace('/.*\./', '', $string);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`substr($str, strrpos($str, '.')+1);`

`strrpos()` will return the position of the last instance of a character in a string.  Use that value + 1 as the starting position in `substr()` to get everything after that.

Comment: All his example data has .

Comment: I didn't say they didn't.

Comment: All my strings has a dot fortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You may match these substrings with

```
$s = "packageName.appName.moduleName.eventName.pageNameX";
preg_match('~[^.]+$~', $s, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N2kOS2/1) and a [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/yQqWQj).

**Details**:

- `[^.]+` - 1 or more chars other than `.`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: That's correct. But I think it's better to use `preg_match` instead

Comment: Yes, for standalone strings, sure.

Answer (score 0):

This function will split the package path into components using the period as a delimiter. Then it will return the last component after the last period using the number of components retrieved in array upon splitting the package path.

```
function get_package_name($in_package_path){

  // Split package path into components at the periods.
  $package_path_components = explode('.',$in_package_path);

  // Get the total number of items in components array
  // and subtract 1 to get array index as array indexes start at 0.
  $last_package_path_component_index = count($package_path_components)-1;

// Return the last component of the package path.
  return $package_path_components[$last_package_path_component_index]
}
```